# How to defend Masters thesis?

Tags: masters, thesis

I have to defend my thesis. I have implemented new technique but the results are same(as with the old technique). So how should I defend it? Is this necessary to get the better results or implementation of new technique matters in thesis?

Comment: *I have implemented [a] new technique*...does this mean that you are attempting your second defense of the same thesis?

Comment: No. Its my first and last defense.

Comment: [This comes to mind](https://xkcd.com/1403/)... (don't do that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds as though your major contribution to expanding the extent of human knowledge is in showing how the new technique can be used to confirm results (X) which were obtained by the old technique. So when defending your thesis, you better be very sure that you show how this new technique enhances our understanding of X!!

If you are unsure how to best present this, talk to your advisor. In fact, even if you believe you know how best to present your contribution,  **talk to your advisor!** Take advantage of his/her experience and knowledge of the field to position yourself where your contribution can make the greatest possible impact.

You need to prove that you have expanded human knowledge, so focus on how this is better than the old technique, not on how you have gotten exactly the same results. Again, your advisor should best be able to show you how to do this.

Comment: What will be the advantage of using the new technique if it gives the same results as given by the old technique?

Comment: Muhammad, you've done the research and the implementation, so you are in a position to know! Is it faster? Easier? More cost efficient? Acknowledge the drawbacks, if any, but focus on the advantages.